# Using declared variables to write HTML file with Cypess

Tags: javascript, html, cypress

I am writing a script which searches for any images in Shutterstock with a given search data. I've made a minimal reproducible example which opens the first found image. My purpose is to open a number of found images and grab some data from their pages (let's say, image name).

Throughout the test I need to collect these names for different images to any kind of array and then write them to HTML file. Below is the code. I am an absolute beginner in HTML, so maybe the solution is pretty obvious. I don't understand how I can use previously declared variables in HTML code which is hardcoded and passed to cy.writeFile() function or maybe there's another solution?

```js
describe('htmlTest', () => {
  it('htmlTest', () => {
    cy.visit('https://www.shutterstock.com');
    // Accept cookies if there's a popup
    cy.get('body').then(($parent) => {
      if ($parent.find('.ot-sdk-row').length > 0) {
        cy.get('#onetrust-accept-btn-handler').click();
      }
    });
    //Type in search data
    cy.get('.MuiFormControl-root > .MuiInputBase-root')
      .click()
      .type('3d character');
    cy.get('.mui-ukg7ay-searchBarButtons > .MuiButtonBase-root').click();
    cy.wait(5000);
    cy.get('[data-automation="AssetGrids_GridItemContainer_div"]')
      .first()
      .children()
      .eq(0)
      .invoke('attr', 'href')
      .then(($assetUrl) => {
        var link = Cypress.config('baseUrl') + $assetUrl;
        cy.visit(link);
      });

    cy.get('.MuiTypography-root MuiTypography-body1 mui-t63b03-bold').then(
      (label) => {
        const assetName = label.text(); // The name of opened image
        cy.writeFile('cypress/report/test.html', '<div>hello</div>');
      }
    );
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you had in mind?

```json
    cy.get('.MuiTypography-root MuiTypography-body1 mui-t63b03-bold').then(
      (label) => {
        const assetName = label.text(); // The name of opened image
        cy.writeFile('cypress/report/test.html', `<div>The name of the opened image is ${assetName}.</div>`);
      }
    );
```